# Pushing view controller from AppDelegate

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications, appdelegate

I am just beginning to learn how to implement Push notifications with iOS and Parse.
At the moment, I can send push notifications from the Parse dashboard to the app,the notification is received, as I can see in the Xcode console, but now my issue is that I am not able to open a view controller from the AppDelegate.

This is my code:

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application
didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo
fetchCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UIBackgroundFetchResult))handler {
    // Create empty photo object
    NSString *photoId = [userInfo objectForKey:@"p"];
    NSLog(@"P=%@",photoId);


    UIStoryboard *mainStoryboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle: nil];
    Aceptado *targetViewController = (Aceptado*)[mainStoryboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"servicio_aceptado"];
    UINavigationController *controlador = [[UINavigationController alloc]init];
    [controlador pushViewController:targetViewController animated:YES];

    }
```

As I said, the console show the log `NSLog(@"P=%@",photoId)` , the notification is received, but the view controller is not shown, any warning or error is shown.

Any help is welcome.

Comment: your code seems ok except one thing. you never set the rootviewcontroller. if you want to create navigation controller then make it root view controller or use one in storyboard and set it as rootviewcontroller.

Comment: @MaheshAgrawal, thank you. But setting the rootviewcontroller throws an exception.

Comment: then you can add a navigation controller in your storyboard and set it as root view controller

Comment: @MaheshAgrawal, but then the rest of the app may change, or not?

Comment: it depends upon your app flow. you told that you are using SWRevealViewController. i don't know your app flow when you want navigation to other controllers but if you are pushing any controller then you must need navigation controller.

Comment: @MaheshAgrawal, as I told you, setting the rootViewController throws an exception: Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[Slider1ViewController pushViewController:animated:]:

Answer (score 5):

I have solved my problem like this:

```
 UIStoryboard *mainStoryboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main"
                                                             bundle: nil];

    Aceptado *controller = (Aceptado*)[mainStoryboard
                                                       instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier: @"servicio_aceptado"];
        controller.id_not =_id_not;
        controller.idemployee = _idemployee;
        controller.fullname = _fullname;
        controller.phone = _phone;
        controller.photo = _photo;
        controller.dni = _dni;
        controller.licenseplate = _licenseplate;
        controller.model = _model;
        controller.color = _color;
        controller.latitude = _latitude;
        controller.longitude = _longitude;

    self.window.rootViewController = controller;
```

Now I can pass values to the target view controller from the AppDelegate file, keeping the SWRevealViewController structure.
Thank to all of you for your proposals.

Answer (score 0):

You should not create new NavigationController, but use one existing. Usually it is **rootViewController** property of your key window.

Try this:

```
UINavigationController *controlador = self.window.rootViewController;
```

If you want to display your **targetViewController** in SWRevealViewController you may change your code as this:

```
SWRevealViewController *controlador = (SWRevealViewController)self.window.rootViewController;
[controloador pushFrontViewController:targetViewController animated:YES];
```

If you need display **targetViewController** over SWRevealViewController, use this:

```
WRevealViewController *controlador = (SWRevealViewController)self.window.rootViewController;
[controloador presentViewController:targetViewController
                 animated:YES
               completion:nil];
```

If you need just replace SWRevealViewController with **targetViewController** use this:

```
self.window.rootviewController=targetViewController;
```

But don't forget save your SWRevealViewController in some another property.

Comment: Thank you, I am using SWRevealViewController and an error is thrown using your proposal: Slider1ViewController pushViewController:animated:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

Comment: I have answered my own question. Thank you for your help in any case.

Answer (score 0):

try this code.

```
UIStoryboard *mainStoryboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle: nil];
Aceptado *targetViewController = (Aceptado*)[mainStoryboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"servicio_aceptado"];

UINavigationController *navVc=(UINavigationController *) self.window.rootViewController;

[navVc pushViewController: targetViewController animated:YES];
```

may help you.

Comment: Thank you, your answer is the same as VChemezov, a exception is thrown": Slider1ViewController pushViewController:animated:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

Comment: Is Slider1ViewController a viewController or UINavigationController

Comment: I have answered my own question. Thank you for your help in any case.

Answer (score 0):

Try this once.

```
UIStoryboard *storyBoard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
Slider1ViewController *viewcontroller = [storyBoard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Slider1ViewController"];

UINavigationController *navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:viewcontroller];
[navController setViewControllers: @[viewcontroller] animated: YES];

[self.revealViewController setFrontViewController:navController];
[self.revealViewController setFrontViewPosition: FrontViewPositionLeft animated: YES];
```

Comment: Thank you, but I don't want to open Slider1ViewController, I want to open Aceptado (another view controller)

Comment: then just replace the viewcontroller.

Comment: I have answered my own question. Thank you for your help in any case.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SomePageViewController *someVC = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"SomeVC"];

self.navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:someVC];
self.window.rootViewController = self.navController;

[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

Comment: I have answered my own question. Thank you for your help in any case.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to push a view controller into navigation stack from appDelegate you need to cast your rootView controller as UINavigation Controller

Comment: Welcome to SO. If you can explain more with code that would be helpful.

Comment: self.window!.rootViewController = UINavigationController(yourRootVC)